# How to get the rectangular coordinates from list of line string

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, postgis-2.2

I have a linestring geometry in my PostgreSQL database. I want to get the corner coordinates of the rectangular bounding box. Example

```
"0102000020E610000002000000CCDA5CEB41D323406E2A9CEE86C54A40CCDA5CEB41D323406E2A9CEE86C54A40"
"0102000020E610000002000000AF5FB01BB6CD22407C7E18213C8E4A40AF5FB01BB6CD22407C7E18213C8E4A40"
```

Until now, I have executed the query

```
SELECT ST_Extent(geomtery) as bextent from warning_060219;
```

result

```
BOX(6.84285 51.37265,11.55307 54.36356)
```

How can I get the four corner coordinates of the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ST_Xmin, ST_Xmax, ST_Ymin and ST_Ymax

```
WITH ext AS 
 (SELECT ST_Extent(geomtery) as bextent 
  from warning_060219)
SELECT
  ST_Xmin(bextent), 
  ST_Xmax(bextent), 
  ST_Ymin(bextent),
  ST_Ymax(bextent)
FROM ext;
```